# How to use beforeSave in CakePHP 3? $event, $entity and $options must be always filled?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm inside **"PostsTable.php"** I'm trying to get form data to treat image files.

In CakePHP 2, I used to do:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array())
{
if(!empty($this->data['Post']['picture']['name'])...
```

Someone could explain this in Cake 3:

```
beforeSave
Cake\ORM\Table::beforeSave(Event $event, Entity $entity, ArrayObject $options)
```

?

**ADDED**

I try this snippet of code to see if I'm able to save this field on database just as a test but it seems beforeSave is being ignored:

```
public function beforeSave($options)
{ 
if(!empty($entity->pic1['name'])) 
{ 
$entity->pic1 = 'jus a test';
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Start with the function definition.

```
Cake\ORM\Table::beforeSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options)
```

Since CakePHP is calling the function automatically, this is how it is being called, so build your function identically to the function definition:

```
// In PostsTable.php
public function beforeSave($event, $entity, $options) {

}
```

If you aren't sure what data is being sent, use CakePHP's `debug()` function:

```
    debug($event); debug($entity); debug($options);
```

Once you find your data in `$entity` use it to do what you want to do to your data:

```
    if (!empty($entity->picture['name'])) { ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that I used:

```
use Cake\Event\Event;
public function beforeSave(Event $event)
{
    $entity = $event->getData('entity');
    if(!empty($entity->picture['name']){
       // your action here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Let me [read the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforesave) for you:

> The Model.beforeSave event is fired before each entity is saved. Stopping this event will abort the save operation. When the event is stopped the result of the event will be returned.

Also:

> Model.beforeSave: Will be triggered just before the list of fields to be persisted is calculated. It receives both the entity and the options as arguments. The options array is passed as an ArrayObject, so any changes in it will be reflected in every listener and remembered at the end of the event so it can be used for the rest of the save operation. Returning false in any of the listeners will abort the saving process. If the event is stopped using the event API, the event object's result property will be returned. This can be useful when having your own saving strategy implemented inside a listener.

To do whatever you did before in Cake2 you can simply modify `$entity` because entities have replaced the `Model::$data` property.

```
if(!empty($entity->picture['name'])
```

If you don't know how events work [read about them](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html). Also [the migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html) is a must read. It lists everything that has changed.

Comment: I've changed it but the beforeSave seems to be ignored. I tried this I added to the question just as a test but the name isn't set.

Comment: @burzump just happened here is: I got what I was trying to do but I used beforeMarshal instead beforeSave. Is there any problem? I only want to save the path in database and the file in a folder. But beforeSave seems to be ignored...

Comment: Read the manual ;) `You can use the Model.beforeMarshal event to modify request data before it is converted into entities.` I have no idea why it's not working for you.